# Using a database_alias other than default when saving/populating a ModelForm

Tags: django, multiple-databases

I am currently having some issues getting ModelForms to behave consistently using multiple databases.

I have an project that uses multiple databases. Each model resides in one db or another so I don't need to load from one and save in another.

```
sale = Sale.objects.using(db_alias).get(pk=sale_id)
form = SaleForm(request.POST, instance=sale)

if form.is_valid():
    form.save();
```

the above works fine.

```
sale = Sale.objects.using(db_alias).get(pk=sale_id)
ssh = History.objects.using(db_alias).get(pk=sale.history_id)

form = SaleForm(request.POST, instance=sale)
sshForm = HistoryForm(request.POST, instance=ssh)

if form.is_valid():
    form.save();
    sshnew = sshForm.save(commit=False)
```

the above does not work fine... form.save() is happy. sshForm.save() complains about not being able to connect to the database (as it defaults to 'default' which is just a place holder)

I can not work out why form and sshForm perform differently when they have been populated similarly.